# jquery callback - pass id after animate method

Tags: jquery, callback

I tried to pass a div id after to make a animation call in JQUERY to dissapear the id, but for some reason the div dissapear in the middle of animation :(

```
function onMouseOut() {

    $('#tdgoogle').mouseout(function(evento) {

        $('#div1').css("display", "block");

        $('#fotogoogle').animate({
            marginLeft : "0px"
        }, 500, callBackGoogle("div1"));

        function callBackGoogle(cadena) {

            $(cadena).css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also do like this `var xFn = callBackGoogle('#div1'); $('#fotogoogle').animate({marginLeft : "0px"},500, xFn);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a wrapper function, like this

```
    $('#fotogoogle').animate({
        marginLeft : "0px"
    }, 500, function() {

        callBackGoogle("div1");
    });
```

Also, change div1 to #div1

Answer (score 0):

use proper selector, for `id` you need to use `#`:

```
$(cadena).css("display", "none");
```

to

```
$("#" + cadena).css("display", "none");
```

Update:

```
....
$('#fotogoogle').animate({
            marginLeft : "0px"
}, 500, function() { callBackGoogle("div1")});

function callBackGoogle(cadena) {    
    $("#" + cadena).css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: THX but still doesnt work... function callBackGoogle(cadena){
 $('#'+cadena).css("display","none"); 
}

Answer (score 0):

it may be just human sight limitation. if you slow down the animate you might found it's did not disappear in the middle of the adnimation

```
  $('#tdgoogle').mouseout(function(evento) {
    $('#fotogoogle').css("margin-left",0);
    $('#div1').css("display", "block");

    $('#fotogoogle').animate({
        marginLeft  : "100px"
    }, 500,function(){ callBackGoogle("#div1")});

    function callBackGoogle(cadena) {
        $(cadena).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4e7s/3/)